# Comments closed only for contributors

Tags: comments, hooks

I am having a very funny issue right now. My WordPress is currently with comments activated and it always worked, but now that I've opened the website for contributors, only their posts are coming with comments closed by default, and only with `post`. I have two custom post types `lista` and `galeria` that aren't having this kind of issue. Any other role also doesn't have this issue.

Already searched through all my source code to find some `closed` or `comment_status`snippets but no luck. Is there any hook that I can dump to see if there is a function intercepting the comment_status for these roles?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English,
Vinicius

Comment: Hi Vinicius. What do you mean by opening the website for contributors? And how did you do it?

Comment: Hi Bernie! I am using a plugin called Userpro to let users create their accounts and make new posts, all the posts must be moderated by our team in order to be published